# Package that receives a number #1 and return #1-1

Tags: calculations

I'm working with a counter but I'm having some problems with the index.

This is my problem:

I'm using a command with `\arabic{#1}` with some input `#1`. But I need to print `\arabic{#1-1}`.

I would like to know if there is some package that receives a number `#1` and return the number `#1-1`.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you meant `\@arabic` instead of `\arabic`? The former expects a number, the latter a counter name.

The calculation can be done in an expandable way via e-TeX's `\numexpr`:

```
\@arabic{\numexpr(#1)-1\relax}
```

Package `intcalc` also supports non-e-TeX:

```
\@arabic{\intcalcDec{#1}}
```

Both commands are working very well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{intcalc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\testA}[1]{\@arabic{\numexpr(#1)-1\relax}}
\newcommand*{\testB}[1]{\@arabic{\intcalcDec{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\testA{1}, \testA{2}, \dots, \testA{1000}

\testB{1}, \testB{2}, \dots, \testB{1000}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: The command is not working )=

Comment: @MiguelRomán Of course, they are working, see updated answer. You can edit your question to clarify, what you are doing (MWE, ...).